# Import changes into a git repository from universal diff

Tags: git, diff

I'm trying to import changes from one source control system (proprietary and complicated) into a git repository. I'm doing this currently by running a script that simply syncs to each revision in order and commits this to the git repository, but for various reasons this has become unworkable.

For each revision, I can get a universal diff describing the change. To me it seems that this should be enough to import history to git, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get git to do this. It looks like I need something in-between git-apply and git-fast-import. Perhaps I should construct the file contents from the previous version and the diff, then use git-fast-import? Or perhaps I should format the diff as a git patch, save it as a file, and use git-apply?

Anyone got any good ideas for me?

EDIT: The reason syncing and committing has become unworkable is twofold:

First, the server maintains a list of files you have edited. Syncing with edited files can't be automated easily, so I revert my changes while updating. We have a checkin queue system that only allows you to checkin when nobody in front of you has any of the same files 'on edit' as you. So taking files 'off edit' to update creates a window where it looks like people can safely jump ahead of you.

Second, all branches are stored in the same repository, and we make heavy use of branches. Syncing everything is easy and works, syncing just one directory (that of the branch I'm on) seems buggy. If I sync everything though, the other branches are updated when I don't want them to be. This normally wouldn't be a problem but we have another tool, which makes things... complicated.

Comment: Oh, hopefully done editing the answer.

Comment: Can you tell us which system it is? Isn't it ClearCase or Synergy? Maybe somebody knows the particular system and can tell you how to get the full texts from it without actually syncing anything (most systems including ClearCase have a command to get particular revision of particular file without checking the file out and if you found one, you could use it with fast-import).

Comment: You're right, that would be perfect! I doubt there are many who know it well though - it's called 'Source Depot', an internal tool used by Microsoft. As far as I understand, it's a very old fork of Perforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what your "various reasons this has become unworkable" are, but I have been doing this exact thing at work successfully for quite a while, so I'm familiar with the pitfalls.  The trick is to keep your upstream in a separate branch such that you can *always* do a sync and a `git commit` without generating conflicts.  I use my master branch for this purpose. My workflow to check in a new feature from a feature branch is something like this:

1. git checkout master
2. sync to centralized VCS
3. git add -A
4. git commit -m "Synced from upstream"
5. git merge feature
6. check in to centralized VCS
7. git checkout -b nextfeature

I don't bother getting every single revision from upstream, but you could do that by just doing steps 2-4 for each upstream revision.

Comment: Yep, that's basically exactly what my current script does! Including repeating 2-4 for each version (I like having history so I can blame colleagues for problems). I've just updated my question to say what the problem with syncing is. I'd like to avoid syncing the other VCS, really.

Comment: Righto, I'm going to continue with this route since there doesn't appear to be a better way to do it. I'll just have to improve my script to do the un-edit and re-edit automatically to minimise the window of time I have no apparent changes. I've found a way round the problem of updating other branches - turned out I just had the syntax wrong. Pretty easy to do with such an outdated system!

Answer (score 4):

- The `apply` command that takes a unified diff and applies it (i.e. there is no "git patch format", it simply unified diff; also `git apply -` will happily read standard input, so no need to save anything).
- The `am` command takes an mbox-formatted file with patches and applies and commits each of them. You might be able to easily generate this; it's simply:

  ```
  From au@th.or Mon, 23 May 2011 14:49:12 +0200
  From: au@th.or
  Date: Mon, 23 May 2011 14:49:12 +0200
  Subject: First line of commit message
  Content-length: <bytes-until-next From>

  Other lines of commit message
  ---
  unified diff
  ```

  concatenated for all the revisions.
- It indeed seems `fast-import` does not accept diffs, but can't you just ask the source system to give you the content of the revision instead (that would handle binary files for which unified diff can't be constructed)? If not, you can ask `fast-import` to give you the previous content (with `cat-blob` command), patch it and feed it in again.

Comment: Ah, I'd not even considered binary files. You're right, I can't use diffs to import changes to binary files. I can get the content of the revision, yes, but it's problematic (that's what I was doing before). It's not so problematic though, when getting individual files. So what I'm now thinking is that I use `git apply` to import text file changes, then at each revision check if there were any binary modifications, then sync those files and amend the commit. I'll investigate that now.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't seem like it'll be completely reliable, the VCS has some weird behaviour. Back to square 1 :)