# How do I import a range of commits I git fast-exported to a file with fast-import?

Tags: git, git-fast-import

I exported a range of commits (a branch) via `git fast-export` using:

```
$ git fast-export master...zzz-utumno-refactoring_master > my_original_utumno_r\
efactoring_master_branch_before_rebases
```

Now I am trying to reimport it. The closest I got was:

```
$ cat my_original_utumno_refactoring_master_branch_before_rebases | git fast-im\
port
fatal: Branch name doesn't conform to GIT standards: master...zzz-utumno-refacto
ring_master
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_4268
```

Edit: had also tried:

```
$ git fast-import < my_original_utumno_refactoring_master_branch_before_rebases
fatal: Branch name doesn't conform to GIT standards: master...zzz-utumno-refacto
ring_master
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_4720
```

[git-fast-import](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fast-import.html) does not give me any clues. How should I proceed ?

Some links I did not quite grok:

- [Malformed branch name in fast-export when specifying non-HEAD/branch revision](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Malformed-branch-name-in-fast-export-when-specifying-non-HEAD-branch-revision-td6696114.html)
- [Import changes into a git repository from universal diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097383/import-changes-into-a-git-repository-from-universal-diff/6097467#6097467)
- [Using git fast-export to export a repo starting at a given commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016375/using-git-fast-export-to-export-a-repo-starting-at-a-given-commit/19044468#comment38285403_19044468)

Comment: First, are you sure that the `fast-export` is actually working? It could be that it is producing an error report and storing that in `my_original_utumno_refactoring_master_branch_before_rebases`. Second, you could try `<` redirection: `git fast-import < my_original_utumno_refactoring_master_branch_before_rebases`

Comment: @tbekolay: export seemed to work - no errors and the file produced was 135 mb - not a crash report. Had tried redirection - same error - edited the question

Comment: I think I should specify where to apply the commits somehow...

Comment: Perhaps you can't use the `...` syntax in the export (although this would be a bug in fast-export if so)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I opened the file with HxD - I see a `commit master...zzz-utumno-refactoring_master` piece of text - what should I replace it with ?

Comment: No idea sorry .. I've only use fast-export with whole repo at a time, not individual branch. I guess you could global replace it with something that didn't contain "..." and see what happens.